# Understanding solr's schema.xml

Tags: search, solr, xsd

I'm a total beginner in `solr`. I've installed it and started working on its `schema.xml` file. One particular code snippet is as follow:
[`schema.xml` comes in the `example/solr/collection1/conf` directory]

```
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
          add enablePositionIncrements=true in both the index and query
          analyzers to leave a 'gap' for more accurate phrase queries.
        -->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
    -->
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
    -->
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

I don't understand the above code in the sense, what is the use of this line:

```
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
```

I guess it is just portraying example by using `synonyms.txt` file in the same directory. Now how should I modify my above code to exclude the example and make it working for a general case?

Answer (score 0):

Just comment out that line. Filters (both Char and Token types) are all optional. Only a tokenizer needs to be present.

If you are still having troubles, start with using just string type (no tokenizers). Then switch to a very basic type that has generic tokenizer, then build it up.

Answer (score 0):

The example specifies a field type by name `text_en` which has

- Defined a set to Tokenizer and filters which would be applied to the terms of the field which get mapped by the field type.
- Allows you to define different set of filters sequence at both index time and search time
- Would determine the behavior of your indexed terms and how search would behave.

You can check for a Complete list of Analyzers @ [Link](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters) with the examples.

You can always define a new field type and map the fields to that field type
For e.g. if you want to make your searches case insensitive would use just a lower case filter.

So tune the filters as per the requirement.

[SynonymFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory) would help you define Synonyms for terms e.g. Automobile, Vehicle which mean the same but are different words.
So if you want the searches to resolve synonyms, you would use this filter and the synonyms are defined in a text file within the Solr core conf directory.